# SQL Server stored procedure that grants itself EXECUTE permission

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, access-control, sql-grant

Tried searching for this but was not able to find anything. I have a handful of stored procedures in a production database where the developer has, at the very end, added a

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON [ProcName] to [USER1] AS [dbo]
```

My spidy sense tells me this should not be done as all user access should be (and is) managed in SSMS at the appropriate level. This also can introduce deadlocks should the database start to really get busy and continually granting this access each time should not be necessary.

I can't for the life of me think of a valid reason why this would need to be done other than to ensure the user gets the permission maybe during development. I plan on removing this, but I was just wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: Most likely, the deployment scripts were missing a `GO` batch terminator between the proc and subsequent `GRANT` so the statement became part of the stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No... you're NOT missing a thing.  This is actually a pretty common thing for a lot of "developers" to do and the developer needs to be pulled up on the carpet for it.  The CTO, the Dev Manager, and the DBAs should join them if one of these makes it through and is one of the primary reasons why...

1. Developers should never be allowed to deploy code to staging, UAT, or Prod
2. why there should be a 100% code review process
3. why there should be written rules about such things with absolutely no tolerance for such things. IMHO, "one and done, you're out'a here".

Companies have enough of a problem with security without the people they're paying doing this type of stupid thing.  There should be zero tolerance for this type of thing.

If this all makes me sound brutal on this subject, then I've succeeded in saying what needs to be said on this subject but then you (the reader) might be a part of the problem.

**{EDIT}**
Let me qualify this a bit more...

This MAY be legitimate as a part of a deployment script but it should NEVER be a part of an actual stored procedure because there is no reason to constantly grant the same privs to a given stored procedure.  This is still a "violation" to me because Developers should not be assigning privs by code or any other way.  Only the DBAs should be assigning such privs and there needs to be a ticket or some other traceability as to why the privs were necessary in order to be able to pass a security audit.

There is also no reason to grant execution privs at the DBO level to a given user.  You should only grant EXECUTE privs to the user and the stored procedure should have the proper WITH EXECUTE AS xxxxx statement in it to be able to accomplish what the stored procedure needs to do.

If "user1" in the grant code is a Developer, then it's time to put the Developer on the spot as to why they're doing such a thing.  But, like I said, this code shouldn't actually exist.  It should be up to the DBAs to grant such privs.

If it's an existing stored procedure where a legitimate user needs it to execute with "dbo" level privs, the stored procedure likely needs to be repaired using WITH EXECUTE AS xxxxx instead of granting individuals such privs.

As with all else in SQL Server, "IT DEPENDS" and there may be a very rare exception to what I've stated but I'd find a different way to make it work, especially if the cited "user1" was a public face application.

Comment: Thanks Jeff...This is inherited code from past developers, and in checking more of them I see that some were missing the GO so the GRANT became part of the proc, but some did not. Agreed that this is sloppy and should not have gotten past code review. (If it ever happened to begin with)

Comment: Agreed, it should never be part of the actual proc and was most likely a miss by the developer to either remove it completely after development or add the GO before it so it does not get compiled. In my past life as a developer, I'd never done this in my procs even during development; was never necessary and I'd never come across it as a legitimate need in production as a DBA so was surprised to see it and thus wondered if I "didn't get the memo" on this approach.  To clarify, "user1" is actually a db role, but, as noted, privs should not be done in the proc every time it runs.

Comment: Thanks for he feedback Karl.  It's always good to know more details on the background of such questions.

Answer (score 3):

99.999% chance this is a mistake.  A stored procedure is ended *only* by the end of a batch.  The developer probably created the procedure with a DDL batch like this:

```
create procedure foo
as
begin
  print 'foo'
end

grant execute on foo to User1 as dbo  --this is still part of the procedure!
go
```

And stored procedures execute as the caller, by default, and the caller wouldn't be able to run that GRANT without being an admin.

It's a good practice to include GRANTs in your DDL scripts, but having seperate GRANTs for each object is a practice that dates from the time before good tools (like SSDT), and before user-schema seperation.

Today it's better practice to GRANT at the schema level, so there's no need to set permissions for each object.  And while GRANTs should be part of the schema design, and be the same across environments, those grants should normally be a GRANT to a ROLE on a SCHEMA.  Then in the different environments the ROLEs may have different members but the GRANTs never change.

So a production DBA might run

```
ALTER ROLE APP_FRONT_END ADD MEMBER [MyDomain\AppPoolIdentity]
```

but not

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FOO TO [MyDomain\AppPoolIdentity]
```

Comment: Thanks David...Agreed that it was probably more of a mistake then purpose. As commented on Jeff's answer, this is inherited code from past developers, and some were missing the GO so the GRANT became part of the proc.  I'm new to SO and I see that I can only award one solution as the best answer, but I think both were valid. For this question, I think it was more of a mistake, as you indicated, on the developers part (as well as others for letting it get past into production) but I'm also in agreement with Jeff as to holding folks accountable.

Comment: To make up for only being able to mark one correct answer, I voted up @DavidBrowne 's post and your comment above.  Thanks for the feedback above, as well.

Comment: SSDT does this by default, if you scroll down to the end of you stored procedures, you will see GRANT statements included.